# Python create shell for several processes

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, call

I have several command execution in python on Windows using subprocess.call(), but for each one I need to execute batch file with environmet setup before calling proper command, it looks like this

```
subprocess.call(precommand + command)
```

Is there way to "create" shell in python that will have batch file executed only once and in that shell command will be executed several times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write commands to a bat-file (`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`)
2. Run the bat-file (`subprocess.check_call(bat_file.name)`)

(not tested):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', suffix='.bat', delete=False) as bat_file:
    print(precommand, file=bat_file)
    print(command, file=bat_file)
rc = subprocess.call(bat_file.name)
os.remove(bat_file.name)
if rc != 0:
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(rc, bat_file.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to get output from every command separately? If no - you can convey these commands using &&, || or ;

```
cd dir && cp test1 test2 && cd -
```

Comment: And here goes problem that those commands are quite long, so only 10% of them can be executed due to too long command